# Why can't Python function declare a sub-function as a global object?

Tags: python

So I used to hear that Python deal with functions as first class objects, then why is it that this fails?

```
def func():
    global add
    def add():
        print('hi')
add()
```

Error: undefined add

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can.

But `func` hasn't been run yet in your example, so the `add` function hasn't been created.

Try the following;

```
def func():
    global add
    def add():
        print("hi")

func()
add()
```

I can't think of a sensible reason as to why you would actually do this - but now you know.

Comment: Just for the record, the reason why I need to do this, is because I have a function that defines a tensorflow graph, and when I create a new neural net, I need to redefine the graph, so, I'm asking a function to redefine that function via exec(inspect.getsource(func))

Answer (score 3):

it fail because you do not call

> func()

that defines

> global add

If you call it, then it defines "add" and it works:

```py
def func():
    global add
    def add():
        print('hi')

func()
add()
### result:
hi
```

Comment: OMG I cannot believe how dumb I am